Dynamic string/name input inside doxygen aliases in C
Anyone knows if its possible to have dynamic names inside aliases for doxygen in C.
example:
ALIASES      += "unitname=TheName"

Here I want to set TheName according to which file it comes from or one possibility would be in header of the c or h-file to add @unitname{TheName}, but is it possible somehow?
Then use this @unitname inside another doxygen tag example:
ALIASES      += "callback{1}=\unitname_\1"

In h-file:
/** 
* @unitname{unit1}
*/


/** 
* @trace{GetName}
*/
void GetName(...){}

Expected output:
unit1_GetName
Then for another unit I want in top add
@unitname{unit2}
Then only new traces in the function in that file and such...

Which version of doxygen are you using? The question is a bit unclear, would be nice to have an example where the files / usage of the commands is shown! Maybe you are referring to something like \fileinfo?

Using Doxygen 1.9.8.

Rewrote the Q a bit hope its more clear.

It is a bit clearer although the definition of @trace is not supplied (probably something what you initial mentioned as @callback and the original @unitname has no argument whilst the used @unitname has an argument). So when I understand it correctly, you want to set a variable and use its value for subsequent commands and furthermore the file name has nothing to do with the value of the @unitname to be used. I don't think this is possible as doxygen won't store the result of @unitname{unit1}

Corrent that was my intension, but if not possible, hmm let see whats the best way then :/
